# Azure ItemPaged iterator doesn't raise StopIteration

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to list all the Linked Services in my ADF account using Azure ADF SDK. The below code prints the results for the first 50 items and then appears to get "stuck" until it is cancelled manually. How do I iterate over the ItemPaged iterator to print the complete result set?

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.datafactory.models import *
import time

subscription_id = ""
tenant_id       = ""
client_secret = ""
client_id = ""

credentials = ClientSecretCredential(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, tenant_id=tenant_id)
adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

for _, row in enumerate(adf_client.linked_services.list_by_factory('my-resource-group', 'my-data-factory')):
  print(_, row.name)
```

**Edit:** I get an *HttpResponseError: (InternalError) Internal error has occurred*. error message if I wait long enough. This issue was reported on the azure-sdk-for-python repo on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/26446).